# Error in notamf(mf) : objeto 'p' não encontrado

Tags: r

O código abaixo é pra meu primeiro programa da faculdade.
Como eu chamo o dado de uma função dentro de outra???
Eu preciso dessas 3 funções para a entrega do programa, porem aparece o erro

""Error in notamf(mf) : objeto 'p' não encontrado""

obs.: quando eu insiro -1 em alguma prova, p1 ou p2, o resultado a ser considerado é a nota da prova substitutiva...

obs2.: existe um comentario na ultima linha, pq falta preencher a situação do aluno, depois de calculado a mf (media final)

---

```
n <- as.numeric(readline("Digite o numero de alunos na sala: "))

for (i in 1:n) {
  nome <- readline("Digite o nome do aluno: ")

    p1<- as.numeric(readline("Digite a nota da P1: "))
    p2<- as.numeric(readline("Digite a nota da P2: "))
    psub<- as.numeric(readline("Digite a nota da PSub: "))
    ep1<- as.numeric(readline("Digite a nota do EP1: "))
    ep2<- as.numeric(readline("Digite a nota do EP2: "))
    ep3<- as.numeric(readline("Digite a nota do EP3: "))

notap <- function(p){
  if(p1== -1){
    p<-as.numeric((p2+psub)/2)
}else if(p2== -1){
    p<-as.numeric((p1+psub)/2)
}else{
  p <-as.numeric((p1+p2)/2)
}
return(p)
}

notaep <- function(ep){
  ep <- (ep1 + 2*ep2 + 2*ep3)/5
  return(ep)
}


notamf <- function(mf){

  if(p>=5 && ep>=5){
    mf <- (3*p+ep)/4


  }else{
    if(p>ep){
      mf <- ep
    }else{
      mf <- p
    }

  }
  return(mf)
}

print(paste0("nome = ", nome))
print(paste0("P1= ",p1))
print(paste0("P2= ",p2))
print(paste0("PSub= ",psub))
print(paste0("A média das provas P= " , notap(p)))
print(paste0("A média dos EPs, EP= ", notaep(ep)))
print(paste0("A média final, MF= ", notamf(mf)))
#print(paste0("A situação do aluno ", nome , " é ", situacao))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O seguinte funciona e é mais simples. Aqui vão alguns dos erros no código original.

1. **Nunca** defina as funções dentro do ciclo `for`.
2. As funções calculavam valores a partir de o que o usuário introduzia mas esses valores do usuário não eram argumentos das funções. Estava a definir funções com os valores de saída como argumentos (dados de entrada).

Código corrigido.

```
notap <- function(p1, p2, psub){
  if(p1 == -1){
    p <- (p2 + psub)/2
  }else if(p2 == -1){
    p <- (p1 + psub)/2
  }else{
    p <- (p1 + p2)/2
  }
  p
}

notaep <- function(ep1, ep2, ep3){
  ep <- (ep1 + 2*ep2 + 2*ep3)/5
  ep
}

notamf <- function(p, ep){
  if(p >= 5 && ep >= 5){
    mf <- (3*p + ep)/4
  }else{
    mf <- max(p, ep)
  }
  mf
}

lerTeclado <- function(texto){
  tcl <- readline(texto)
  as.numeric(tcl)
}

n <- lerTeclado("Digite o numero de alunos na sala: ")

for (i in 1:n) {
  nome <- readline("Digite o nome do aluno: ")

  p1 <- lerTeclado("Digite a nota da P1: ")
  p2 <- lerTeclado("Digite a nota da P2: ")
  psub <- lerTeclado("Digite a nota da PSub: ")
  ep1 <- lerTeclado("Digite a nota do EP1: ")
  ep2 <- lerTeclado("Digite a nota do EP2: ")
  ep3 <- lerTeclado("Digite a nota do EP3: ")

  p <- notap(p1, p2, psub)
  ep <- notaep(ep1, ep2, ep3)
  mf <- notamf(p, ep)

  cat("nome =", nome, "\n")
  cat("P1 =", p1, "\n")
  cat("P2 =", p2, "\n")
  cat("PSub =", psub , "\n")
  cat("A média das provas P =" , p, "\n")
  cat("A média dos EPs, EP =", ep, "\n")
  cat("A média final, MF =", mf, "\n")
}
```